# org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Unknown mobile command "clickGesture"

Tags: java, automation, appium, gesture, appium-android

I am getting this error despite existing documentation indicating that this command isn't depracated.

Here is my code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;

public class AndroidGestures {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AppiumDriver driver = CreateDriverSession.initializeDriver("Android");
        // longClickGesture(driver);
        clickGesture(driver);
    }

    public static void clickGesture(AppiumDriver driver) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("Views"));

        driver.executeScript("mobile: clickGesture", ImmutableMap.of(
                "elementId", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId()
        ));
    }

    public static void longClickGesture(AppiumDriver driver) {
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("Views")).click();
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("Drag and Drop")).click();
        //accessibilityId would not work for dot, unable to locate
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.view.View[1]"));

        driver.executeScript("mobile: longClickGesture", ImmutableMap.of(
           "elementId", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId(),
//                use coordinates instead of center click:
//                "x",217,
//                "y",659,
                "duration", 1000
        ));
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get when I run the class:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Unknown mobile command "clickGesture". Only shell,execEmuConsoleCommand,dragGesture,flingGesture,doubleClickGesture,longClickGesture,pinchCloseGesture,pinchOpenGesture,swipeGesture,scrollGesture,scrollBackTo,scroll,viewportScreenshot,viewportRect,deepLink,startLogsBroadcast,stopLogsBroadcast,acceptAlert,dismissAlert,batteryInfo,deviceInfo,getDeviceTime,changePermissions,getPermissions,performEditorAction,startScreenStreaming,stopScreenStreaming,getNotifications,listSms,type,sensorSet,deleteFile,clearApp,startActivity,startService,stopService,broadcast,getContexts,installMultipleApks,unlock commands are supported.
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_301'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [0b00a050-d9de-49e8-948f-ce6392f1d867, executeScript {script=mobile: clickGesture, args=[{elementId=00000000-0000-01d0-ffff-ffff00000014}]}]
Capabilities {appium:app: /Users/fieldemployee/IdeaPr..., appium:appPackage: io.appium.android.apis, appium:automationName: uiAutomator2, appium:avd: Nexus_5_API_29, appium:avdLaunchTimeout: 280000, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {app: /Users/fieldemployee/IdeaPr..., automationName: uiAutomator2, avd: Nexus_5_API_29, avdLaunchTimeout: 280000, deviceName: nexus_5, newCommandTimeout: 300, platformName: android, udid: emulator-5554}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 29, appium:deviceManufacturer: Google, appium:deviceModel: Android SDK built for x86, appium:deviceName: emulator-5554, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 408, appium:deviceScreenSize: 1080x1920, appium:deviceUDID: emulator-5554, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:newCommandTimeout: 300, appium:pixelRatio: 2.55, appium:platformVersion: 10, appium:statBarHeight: 61, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:udid: emulator-5554, appium:viewportRect: {height: 1737, left: 0, top: 61, width: 1080}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: ANDROID}
Session ID: 0b00a050-d9de-49e8-948f-ce6392f1d867
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:480)
    at AndroidGestures.clickGesture(AndroidGestures.java:18)
    at AndroidGestures.main(AndroidGestures.java:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the link to the documentation:

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-mobile-gestures/#mobile-clickgesture